# Is there a way to use web sockets with ec2 instance?

Tags: python, node.js, flutter, amazon-ec2, websocket

I'm currently developing a multiplayer gaming app using flutter framework and AWS services. Connections are established through web sockets. I really don't understand how to establish these connections with ec2. Do I need to develop api using node.js or python?
Please note down if there are any useful links.

Answer (score 1):

> WebSockets, on the other hand, allow for sending message-based data, similar to UDP, but with the reliability of TCP. WebSocket uses HTTP as the initial transport mechanism, but keeps the TCP connection alive after the HTTP response is received so that it can be used for sending messages between client and server. WebSockets allow us to build “real-time” applications without the use of long-polling.

https://sookocheff.com/post/networking/how-do-websockets-work/

Seems like something that will work fine for AWS ingress.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is web socket communication is easy with aws amplify??? I chose aws amplify since i saw that it is easy to use with flutter.  I've another problem in choosing the correct aws services. Currently I've chosen EC2 as server and RDS as the database. Is it a right choice for my application???